# How to use dictConfig to configure the logging handler extending QueueHandler?

Tags: python, python-logging, python-3.12

TL;DR *dictConfig* does not work with custom *QueueHandler* implementations in Python 3.12

Following the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#subclass-queuehandler), I implemented a custom QueueHandler which uses ZMQ to send log records to a listener running in another process.

Here is the listener code which reads messages from the socket and passes them to the handler:

```py
# zmq-logging.server.py
DEFAULT_ADDR = 'tcp://localhost:13231'
_context = zmq.Context()
atexit.register(_context.destroy, 0)

class ZMQQueueListener(logging.handlers.QueueListener):
  def __init__(self, address, *handlers):
    self.address = address
    socket = _context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    socket.bind(address)
    super().__init__(socket, *handlers)

  def dequeue(self, block: bool) -> logging.LogRecord:
    data = self.queue.recv_json()
    if data is None:
      return None
    return logging.makeLogRecord(data)
  
  def enqueue_sentinel(self) -> None:
    socket = _context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.connect(self.address)
    socket.send_json(None)

  def stop(self) -> None:
    super().stop()
    self.queue.close(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  listener = ZMQQueueListener(DEFAULT_ADDR, logging.StreamHandler())
  listener.start()
  print('Press Ctrl-C to stop.')
  try:
    while True: time.sleep(0.1)
  finally:
    listener.stop()
```

Here is the handler code which enqueues records in the zmq queue.

```py
# zmq-logging-handler.py
_context = zmq.Context()

class ZMQQueueHandler(logging.handlers.QueueHandler):
  def __init__(self, address, ctx=None):
    self.ctx = ctx or _context
    socket = self.ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.connect(address)
    super().__init__(socket)

  def enqueue(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> None:
    self.queue.send_json(record.__dict__)

  def close(self) -> None:
    return self.queue.close()
```

And a dictionary config I used to configure the logger

```py
config = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'formatters': {
    'full': {
      'format': "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s %(message)s",
      'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    }
  },
  'handlers': {
    'zmq-logging': {
      'class': 'zmq-logging-handler.ZMQQueueHandler',
      'formatter': 'full',
      'level': 'DEBUG',
      'address': DEFAULT_ADDR
    }
  },
  'loggers': {
    '': {
      'level': 'DEBUG',
      'propagate': False,
      'handlers': ['zmq-logging']
    }
  }
}
```

However, it no longer works in Python 3.12. The configuration for the *QueueHandler*s changed as described in the [logging.config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuring-queuehandler-and-queuelistener). The handler config requires additional *queue*, *listener* and *handlers* parameters which I do not know how to use with my class model. Should I abandon extending *QueueHandler* or is there a way to fix the config dict?
I don't understand how new *listener* property of the *QueueHandler* can be used if the listener and the handler need to be instantiated in separate processes.